# d3.js Update time domain based on brush selection

Tags: javascript, d3.js, linechart

I am trying to update the time domain (x axis) of a line chart based on the "brush" coordinates on a secondary graph.

fiddle code here - https://jsfiddle.net/6xpcxvwj/7/

```
var brush = d3.brushX()
        .extent([[0, 0], [navWidth, navHeight]])
        .on("end", function () {

            xScale.domain(brush.extent());
            console.log("domain modified");

            svg.select("._x_axis").call(xAxis);
            console.log("x axis modified");

            svg.select("._line").attr("d", line);
            console.log("line modified");
        });
```

For there is something wrong in the above code (which is at the end in the fiddle page) which on updating (moving the brush) the main graph, it removes the x axis and line chart.

The code is based on https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367, but with a big **difference** that my data set is an array, where as in the example it is a csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `d3` version 4, `d3.extent` [no longer works](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush#brush_extent) the same way (you can't use it to get the *brushed* extent).  Instead [this functionality has been abstracted](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush/blob/master/README.md#brush-events) into `d3.event.selection`.  So try:

```
var s = d3.event.selection;
xScale.domain([navXScale.invert(s[0]), navXScale.invert(s[1])]);
```

After fixing that, you'll also need to introduce a clip-path into your plot.

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6xpcxvwj/8/).